# Downloadable Fonts - How to create a custom font-family with different downloaded fonts

Tags: android, fonts, android-8.0-oreo

I have added the support for 2 downloadable fonts in my application. I have added these fonts through Android Studio which generates necessary files like `preloaded_fonts.xml` `font_certs.xml` etc for me. The two fonts are

- `roboto` - for normal textStyle.
- `roboto_bold` - for italic textStyle ( I know I am using roboto_bold for italic textStyle).

I have created a new Font resource file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:font="@font/roboto"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/roboto"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        android:font="@font/roboto_bold"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/roboto_bold"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400" />
</font-family>
```

And I am using it in the following way.

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/custom_font"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/custom_font"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

But this doesn't work. If I directly use `roboto` and `roboto_bold`, then it works perfectly fine. This also works fine when I am using bundled fonts. But while creating a custom font-family and use downloadable fonts, it doesn't work. Did anyone else face this issue? Please help out.

Comment: It is because font provider only provides a cached reference of a font. The fonts are never saved in fonts folder (in case of Downloadable Fonts).

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am trying to solve the same question. It seems like downloadable fonts can't be combined into font-families.